# What OCaml libraries are there for lazy list handling?

Tags: ocaml, backtracking, lazylist

What OCaml libraries are out there that provide lazy list handling? I am looking for something along these lines:

```
type 'a lazy_list = (*'*)
  | Nil
  | Cons of 'a * 'a lazy_list lazy_t

let from f = 
  let rec gen n = 
    lazy 
      (
        match f n with 
          | Some x ->
              Cons (x, gen (n + 1))
          | None ->
              Nil
      )
  in 
    gen 0
```

Integration with the `Stream` type and syntactic sugar for *backtracking* Camlp4 parsers would be nice.

Comment: `Lazy.t` should be used instead of `lazy_t`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Ocaml Batteries](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/) has a [lazy list module](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/doc.preview:batteries-beta1/html/api/Lazy_list.html), check out the `to_stream` function. As for backtracking, you can look into camlp4's stream parsers now that you have a Stream.t .

Comment: Thanks, lazy list module is very handy. Not sure about the stream parsers though as they do not backtrack. But I'll figure it out from here.

Comment: well, camlp4 doesn't backtrack? Maybe I was thinking about camlp5? One of them (or both) does backtracks via continuations...

Comment: Ah yes, that seems be camlp5. Thanks!

http://pauillac.inria.fr/~ddr/camlp5/doc/htmlc/bparsers.html

Comment: The Batteries library now has [three different more or less lazy sequence types](https://github.com/ocaml-batteries-team/batteries-included/wiki/ListTypes), with different properties.

Answer (score 2):

Also, there is a lazy list module called `Cf_seq` in my [OCaml Network Application Environment](http://ocnae.sourceforge.net/) Core Foundation.  In fact, I wrote a whole passle of functional data structures.  It's all available under a 2-clause BSD license.  Enjoy.

**Update**: the code has been renamed "[Oni](https://bitbucket.org/jhw/oni)" and it's now hosted at BitBucket.  You can also use the [GODI](http://godi.camlcity.org/godi/toc/toc-3.11.html) package for it.